# Inject data in json entity with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have JPA entity for department:

```
public class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Basic
    @Column
    @Nationalized
    private String name;

    @Basic
    @Column(length = 400)
    @Nationalized
    private String branch;
    ...
}
```

And REST repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "departments", path = "departments")
public interface DepartmentRestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Department, Long> {
    ...
}
```

Entity's `branch` field is IDs of entity parent departments separated by space, e.g. `1 2 3`.

When I query specific department via `/api/departments/ID` is it possible to attach to it field like `parents` with all parent entities queried?

I tryed to add `getParents` method to entity, but it obviously gave me unneeded parents queries with all entities recursively.

**Update 2019.01.17**:
As a workaround I splitted `Department` entity into `Department` and `DepartmentWithParents`. I added `Department getParents()` method to `DepartmentWithParents` entity and exposed REST API method that returns `DepartmentWithParents`.
Is there better way?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I splitted `Department` entity into `Department` and `DepartmentWithParents`. I added `Department getParents()` method to `DepartmentWithParents` entity and exposed REST API method that returns `DepartmentWithParents`.